# Shortcut for commenting out pipe operator %>% on a line

Tags: r, pipe, tidyverse, keyboard-shortcuts, magrittr

Is there a shortcut to comment out the pipe `%>%` operator for a given line? It would be great to have something like CMD+SHIFT+M+C or something to comment out *just the pipe*. This is useful when you have a long string of pipes and want to check your code along the way (especially for finding errors)

---

Example case (no reprex needed)

```
df %>% 
select(col1, col2) %>%
filter(col1 > 5) %>%
mutate(col_sum = sum(col1, col2))
```

Shortcut to comment out just the pipe operator (say, to just see if the `filter` worked properly)

```
df %>% 
select(col1, col2) %>%
filter(col1 > 5) #%>% 
mutate(col_sum = sum(col1, col2))
```

Comment: I would suggest to have a look at https://github.com/MilesMcBain/breakerofchains.

Comment: Pretty cool! Would love to implement this as a shortcut, but not sure if add-ins allow this or not.

Comment: Yes, they do: https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/#:~:text=Let's%20bind%20Insert%20%25in%25%20to,inserted%20at%20the%20cursor%20position.

Comment: Fantastic! What a great workaround